# Having problems in making a sentence counter using substr

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a sentence counter and I have almost completed it. I have made one But I have a problem, whenever there are multiple *periods, question marks, or exclamation points*, they seem to be counted as well

**html**

```
 <input id="counter" type="text" />
<p id="sntnceCounter">Sentence(s):</p>
```

**js**

```
function myFunction() {
  var counter = document.getElementById("counter").value;
  var sentences = document.getElementById("sntnceCounter");

 for (var i = 0; i < counter.length; i++) {
    var currentCharacter = counter.substr(i, 1);
    var nextCharacter = counter.substr(i + 1, 1);
 if (
      (currentCharacter == "." ||
        currentCharacter == "?" ||
        currentCharacter == "!") &&
      (nextCharacter !== "." || nextCharacter !== "?" || nextCharacter !== "!")
    ) {
      console.log((sntnceCount += 1));
    }
  }

  sentences.innerHTML = "Sentence(s):" + sntnceCount;
}
```

I made the sentence counter by checking if the current character is a *period, question mark, or exclamation point* and also making sure it does not count the next one if there is one. But it still counts them. How do I solve this?

Sorry for poor english

Comment: Use a state-machine. Also consider using `charAt` instead of `substr`.

Comment: "*`substr` is considered a legacy function and should be avoided when possible. It is not part of the core JavaScript language and may be removed in the future.*"

Comment: @adiga - Except it won't. Whoever wrote that sentence knows nothing about how TC39 operates. Pointlessly breaking existing code is very much **not** their thing. :-) It's important to remember that until recently, MDN was entirely community-edited, and some real clangers have managed to creep in... [Here's](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-additional-ecmascript-features-for-web-browsers) the more appropriate warning for Annex B features.

Comment: An alternative to the above would be to use a regular expression for spliting the string to sentences and taking the length of the resulting array `sntnceCount = counter.split(/[.?!]/g).length;`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for the explanation and the link!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change

```js
(nextCharacter !== "." || nextCharacter !== "?" || nextCharacter !== "!")
```

to

```js
(nextCharacter !== "." && nextCharacter !== "?" && nextCharacter !== "!")
```